# Evaluate a differential equation at a given point

Tags: numerical-methods

I have a second order differential equation $x^2\cdot y''(x)+x\cdot y'(x)+(x^2-10)=0$ with the initial condition $y(100)=1$ and $y'(100)=0$. I want to evaluate $y(x)$ when $x=103$ with 8 digit accuracy.

The first step is rewrite this equation to a system of first order equation.
$\begin{cases} y'=w\\ w' = -\frac{w}{x}-\frac{10}{x^2}+1\end{cases}$ with the initial condition $\begin{cases} y(100)=1\\ w(100)=0\end{cases}$. Then I can use fourth-order Runge-Kutta methods to solve the system. In order to achieve 8 digit accuracy, I need to decide the step size $h$. Solving $h^4\le 10^{-8}$, I get $h=0.01$.

Is this seems a reasonable approach? Is there anything special with such a differential equation with the initial condition so that I need use other method to evaluate it?

Comment: The error of RK4 is not $h^4$. It is *of order* $h^4$, meaning that one can bound it by $Ch^4$ where $C$ depends on your equation. I don't have a numerical analysis textbook nearby, so can't give an explicit bound for $C$.

Comment: I got hold of a numerical analysis textbook, *A first course in numerical analysis* by Ralston and Rabinowitz (published by Dover), pages 217-218. The error bounds are a bit too complicated to reproduce here.

Comment: @5pm. Thanks for your comment! I looked at the book you mentioned above but still don't get too much insights for estimating C for my example. Do you have any other good references such as examples for solving systems of differential equations without knowing the exact solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is reasonable to begin with $h=0.01$. Since the theoretical bounds for RK4 are very conservative and also difficult to use, the *step halving method* may be preferable. It is based on running the computations with two or several step sizes and  comparing the results.

For illustration purposes, I used Euler's method (rather than RK4) for this equation. The results were:

- with $h=0.02$, $y(103)\approx 5.4225$
- with $h=0.01$, $y(103)\approx 5.4371$
- with $h=0.005$, $y(103)\approx 5.4443$

Since Euler's method is of 1st order, each result is off by about $Ch$ from the true value. We can estimate $C$ as follows
$$
\frac{5.4225-5.4371}{0.02-0.01} \approx -1.46
$$
$$
\frac{5.4371-5.4443}{0.01-0.005} \approx -1.44
$$
The fact that two values of $C$ are close allows us to conclude confidently that the error is bounded by, say, $2h$ when $h$ is small.

For RK4 the error behaves as $Ch^4$, so you would have the differences like $0.02^4-0.01^4$ in the denominator. Try it (and report the results, if you don't mind).

Answer (score -1):

I think that the method of Frobenius is applicable to this problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that, please?

Comment: The [method of Frobenius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) is intended to obtain a power series representation around the point $x=0$. It would be entirely unproductive to use a power series around $x=0$ to move from $x=100$ to $x=103$.